# c# Combobox in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox

In my winform application there is a datagrid and to insert value from datagrid I am generating comboboxes to some columns using the following code inside a button click event:

```
dgvLoadTable.DataSource = source;
dgvLoadTable.ReadOnly = false;
dgvLoadTable.AllowUserToAddRows = true;

var practices = (from p in context.TOWERIMPORTCLIENTs select p.PRACTICE).Distinct();
for(int r= 0; r < dgvLoadTable.Rows.Count; r++)
{
for(int c = 0; c < dgvLoadTable.Columns.Count; c++)
{
    if(c == 2 || c == 4)
    {
        this.dgvLoadTable[c, r] = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
        foreach(var name in practices)
            ((DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dgvLoadTable[c, r]).Items
                                                          .AddRange(practices.ToArray());
    }
  }
}
```

This is working for the first new row only, when a second new row is generated, it doesn't have comboboxes. So how do I detect if new row is generated?

Comment: what kind of object is `source` ?

Comment: source is an entity model

Answer (score 1):

You could do this using no code at all. Use the designer to add a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` to your datagrid. Bind this column to a `BindingSource` (set the datasource property) which binds to your `List<Practice>` and set the DisplayMember and ValueMember accordingly.

For example:

- Your DataPropertyName would be: Practice (this is a string...?)
- Your datasource would be some bindingsource PracticesBindingSource (see code below)
- Your displaymember would be PRACTICE(string)
- Your valuemember would be PRACTICE (not sure about this)

[image: Property overview of 'Edit Columns']

The binding of your PracticesBindingSource would be very simple:

```
public void BindPractices(DbContext context)
{
    PracticesBindingSource.DataSource = (
       from p in context.TOWERIMPORTCLIENTs 
       select p.PRACTICE
       ).Distinct().ToArray();
}
```

Because you designed your interface like this, your datagridview will behave the same for every row it shows.

You can add the DataGridViewComboBoxColumn in code if you like.

```
public void AddDataGridViewComboBoxColumn(DataGridView dgv, string propertyoBindTo)
{
    var dc = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
    dc.DataSource = this.practicesBindingSource;
    dc.DisplayMember = "PRACTICE";
    dc.ValueMember = "PRACTICE";
    dc.DataPropertyName = propertyToBindTo;
    dgv.Columns.Add(dc);
}
```

Comment: I can't do that, I have 11 tables and each table structure is different. So I have to create the combobox columns on the run time with code.

Comment: you're not creating a comboboxcolumn.... you're creating a combobox cell.... See my edit

Comment: Did creating the column in code help? If not, what are the problems you're still experiencing? And if, could you mark my answer as 'Answer', thanx!

Comment: Nope , I did it in other way. But thanks for your help